# UIView.convertPoint not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to figure out how to use the UIView's convertPoint function in the swift playground. I'm not getting the results I expect and I'm not sure why.

When I Try:

```
import UIKit
let large = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
let small = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let point = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
large.convertPoint(point, toView: small)
```

I expect: `{x: 100, y: 100}`

I actually get: `{x: 200, y: 200}`

What am I missing?

Comment: `convertPoint` will only work if both views have been added to some parent view. Since you never added either view, the conversion makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

change your code (small view) to

```
let large = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
let small = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
let point = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
let convertedPoint = large.convertPoint(point, toView: small)
print(convertedPoint)
```

prints out: **(180.0, 180.0)**

and that is totally correct. take a look at the image:
[image: small view at (20, 20)]

as you can see the red dot is at 200, 200 (exactly in the middle) of the large - dark gray - view and at 180, 180 (near the bottom right) of the small - light gray - view.

if we now get back to your example with the small view's origin at 0, 0 instead of 20, 20 the red dot is at 200, 200 (exactly in the middle) of the large view and also at 200, 200 (exactly at the bottom right) of the small view. look:
[image: small view at (0, 0)]

so the output you get totally makes sense! hope i could help...